# No speedup using parallel restore with pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-11, centos-7

I need a large database like 10TB-15TB in Postgresql for benchmarking.

I've created a smaller ~100GB sample databases with `pgbench` like this:

```
pgbench -i -s 7000 --no-vacuum exampledb
```

However, I observe no speedup when doing parallel restore from `custom` format (created with `pg_dump -F c ...`). Including restoring from `.sql` dump as well:

```
time psql -d pgbench7000 < pgbench7000.sql

SET
SET
SET
SET
SET

set_config
------------
(1 row)

SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET

CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE

CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE

CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE

CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE

COPY 700000000
COPY 7000
COPY 0
COPY 70000

ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE

real        32m1.539s
user        3m28.575s
sys         1m40.125s

####################

time pg_restore -d pgbench7000 pgbench7000.custom
real         20m7.504s
user         2m35.556s
sys          0m35.750s

####################

time pg_restore -j 16 -d pgbench7000 pgbench7000.custom

real         20m56.565s
user         2m57.547s
sys          0m40.096s
```

I've given Postgresql server generous resources:

```
max_connections = 1000              
shared_buffers = 94GB  # 25% of system's memory                
work_mem = 512MB                      
maintenance_work_mem = 12GB
effective_io_concurrency = 500
max_worker_processes = 50     
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 10   
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 10   
max_parallel_workers = 50
```

The box is really powerful, it has 374GB of RAM, 72 vCPUs and fast NAS storage mounted over NFS (that's where PG data directory resides).

`pgbench` creates a rather simple database, there are like four tables and only one table is big and occupies most of space. Can this be the reason for lack of speedup?

Can anybody tell where's the bottleneck? Or is it just db structure?

Environment: Centos 7.9 (that's what I have to use), Postgres 11 installed from project repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel restore does different operations in parallel, but doesn't parallelize individual operations.  Since pgbench is dominated by one table, there isn't much that can be done in parallel for it at the client level.

With some shell scripting, you can run pg_restore multiple times in parallel, pointing each one at a different database name.  (But you could do the same scripting using `pgbench -i -s 7000 $DBNAME &` instead, skipping the dump and reload steps.)

Comment: Take care restoring or populating databases like this in parallel. If you overdo the number of concurrent bulk operations you could saturate the available IO throughput or IOPs or both, even on an impressively specced storage array.